# MongoDB - Inconsistent cursor behavior

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell

Could anyone explain this?

```
    [test] 2014-01-31 18:40:36.243 >>> var rowNEW = db.people.find( { "name" : "joe", "age" : 20} );
    [test] 2014-01-31 18:40:42.853 >>> rowNEW.forEach(function() { print ('FOUND ROW'); } );
    FOUND ROW
    [test] 2014-01-31 18:40:47.163 >>> rowNEW = db.people.find( { "name" : "joe", "age" : 20} );
    { "_id" : ObjectId("52ec316d1d21069b6061b554"), "name" : "joe", "age" : 20 }
    [test] 2014-01-31 18:40:55.73 >>> rowNEW.forEach(function() { print ('FOUND ROW'); } );
    [test] 2014-01-31 18:40:57.533 >>>
```

The first time 'FOUND ROW' **is printed out**.
The second time 'FOUND ROW' **is not printed out**.
This looks very unexpected and weird to me.
Why does it behave that way?

Comment: it is to do with the `var` bit, but I have forgotten exactly what now, it is some kind of scoping issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without the `var` the left side `newRow` is being eval'd in the shell. It's a REPL, that's why you see the JSON on the next line. This also moves the cursor forward one step, so when you are trying to access the `newRow` the next time, the cursor is at the end of the results.

use `var` to avoid the eval.

Comment: I suspected something like this. But what if I want to reuse the same variable. Do I need to say `var row = db.foo.find();` each time (i.e. include the var each time)?

Comment: nothing wrong with saying `var newRow=` over and over again. Javascript or at least this REPL does not care

Comment: OK, thank you. One final thing: is there any way to reset such a cursor back to its starting position, and is that a good practice?

Comment: Not in the shell. Raise a JIRA :) But otherwise this is generally implemented in most drivers. Perfectly fine as long as you accept what you are doing.

Comment: @peter.petrov: To "reset" a cursor, you would execute the query again. Database cursors are only iterated in the forward ("next") direction as you process a result set. If you want to refer to previous results you would have to cache these in your application code or perhaps copy the result set to an array if it is reasonable to fit in RAM. For more examples see: [Iterate a Cursor in the `mongo` Shell](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/).